# How to read multilevel xml?

Tags: java, xml, groovy

It is necessary to go through the entire xml and verify the tag for each "DOCUMENT" record. If the tag contains "IINYUL" or "INNFL", then (further does not apply to this question). How to implement the fastest xml traversal and tag validation?

File XML:

[enter link description here](https://filebin.net/caxu86p7zcpegcvx)

Comment: Java natively supports XQuery: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADXDK/adx_j_xqj.htm#ADXDK99930

Comment: Please add the code you have tried and how it failed (e.g. errors,
stacktraces, logs, ...) so we can improve on it.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to retrieve a particular document.

**XQuery**

```
<root>
{
    for $x in doc('c:\Users\Yitzhak\Downloads\test_z.xml')/Файл/Документ
    where $x/ИПВклМСП/@ИННФЛ="701718575510" 
    return $x
}
</root>
```

**Output**

```
<root>
  <Документ ИдДок="b6a52b88-cf38-4601-89b2-bbea28d0fd49" ДатаСост="10.03.2021" ДатаВклМСП="01.08.2016" ВидСубМСП="2" КатСубМСП="1" ПризНовМСП="2" СведСоцПред="2">
    <ИПВклМСП ИННФЛ="701718575510">
      <ФИОИП Фамилия="ОВСЕЙКО" Имя="АЛЕКСАНДР" Отчество="НИКОЛАЕВИЧ"/>
    </ИПВклМСП>
    <СведМН КодРегион="70">
      <Регион Тип="Область" Наим="Томская"/>
      <Город Тип="Город" Наим="Томск"/>
    </СведМН>
    <СвОКВЭД>
      <СвОКВЭДОсн КодОКВЭД="47.59.1" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная мебелью в специализированных магазинах" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="31.01" НаимОКВЭД="Производство мебели для офисов и предприятий торговли" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="31.02" НаимОКВЭД="Производство кухонной мебели" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="31.09" НаимОКВЭД="Производство прочей мебели" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="46.46" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля оптовая фармацевтической продукцией" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="46.65" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля оптовая офисной мебелью" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="46.90" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля оптовая неспециализированная" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="47.19" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная прочая в неспециализированных магазинах" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="47.59" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная мебелью, осветительными приборами и прочими бытовыми изделиями в специализированных магазинах" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="47.91.2" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная, осуществляемая непосредственно при помощи информационно-коммуникационной сети Интернет" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="47.91.3" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная через Интернет-аукционы" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
      <СвОКВЭДДоп КодОКВЭД="47.91.4" НаимОКВЭД="Торговля розничная, осуществляемая непосредственно при помощи телевидения, радио, телефона" ВерсОКВЭД="2014"/>
    </СвОКВЭД>
  </Документ>
</root>
```